# Javascript - Update a global variable after passing it through a function

Tags: javascript, variables

I am currently studying javascript and I was wondering if there is a way to update a global variable after passing it through a function? Thank you in advance.

PS: Is it possible doing it only with pure javascript (Without jQuery)?

```js
var Number = 0;

function Calculator(){
    Number = Number + 100;
}

console.log(Number);
```

Comment: If you actually call `Calculator` in your example, it would update `Number`. Other than that, it's a little unclear what it is you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

But you didn't execute the function so it doesn't run it

```js
var Number = 0;

function Calculator(){
    Number = Number + 100;
}

Calculator(); // this executes the code in Calculator function

console.log(Number);
```